# Replace number i with i asterisks

Tags: php

How would I write a function that replaces a number to the right amount of stars in PHP, I have done it in JavaScript and tried to translate the whole function to PHP but I dont know that much PHP so I cant seem to figure out what the problem is... can someone please correct me, for now it just prints out 0 regardless of witch nr?

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < count($content_array2); $i++) {
    $values = explode(';', $content_array2[$i]);
    $titels = $values[0];
    $grade = $values[1];
    echo '<li>'.$titels.'<span>'.changeNumber($grade).'</span>'.'</li>';
}
function changeNumber($number) {
    $stars = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
        $stars += "*";
    }
    return $stars;
}
?>
```

Comment: we can't tell without knowing the values of `$content_array2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `.=` to concatenate strings, not `+=`.

```
$stars .= "*";
```

When you use `+=`, PHP considers `$stars` is a numeric value, that's why you get a numeric result.